# How do I assign a variable of DateTime to flspots. Also, how do add title to each axis in flchart?

Tags: flutter, graph, charts

The flSpots in flchart flutter works well with type 'double' but I want to plot double against 'DateTime'

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [how to write a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -1):

You can use the seconds or milliseconds since epoch, depending on what precision you need.

```dart
double x = dateTimeObject.millisecondsSinceEpoch.toDouble();
FlSpot spot = FlSpot(x, y);
```

And to convert it back:

```dart
DateTime dtObject = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(spot.x.toInt());
```